# A question on the coefficients of the Taylor's series of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions, entire-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by $$f(z)=(1-z)e^{\big( z+ \frac{z^2}{2} \big)}=1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nz^n.$$

Then, which of the following is FALSE?

1. $f'(z)=-z^2e^{\big( z+ \frac{z^2}{2} \big)}$
2. $a_1=a_2$
3. $a_n \in (-\infty,0]$
4. $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} |a_n|<1$

**My attempt:**

Straight forward calculations yield that both options 1) and 2) are TRUE.We can see that $a_1=0,a_2=0$ and $a_3=-\frac{2}{6}.$
But that does not guarantee that $a_n \in (-\infty,0]$ for all $n.$

The answer key says that option 4) is FALSE, meaning that 4) is the right answer for this question.

I am stuck here and not able to go ahead.
How to see this ?
Please help and provide some hints.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: what does $f(1)=0$ tell you about the sum on the left-hand side of 4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Taylor coefficients of
$$
f'(z)=-z^2e^{\big( z+ \frac{z^2}{2} \big)}
$$
are zero or negative, which implies that the same is true for the Taylor coefficients of $f$, with the possible exception of the constant coefficient. This proves that (3) is true.

As already said in a comment, you can then use that
$$
 0 = f(1) = 1 + \sum_{n=3}^\infty a_n = 1 - \sum_{n=3}^\infty |a_n| \, .
$$